# Why can't i use an constant in an class field/attribute?

Tags: php, class, constants

Example:

```
const USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = '2';
private $uesrname_error_message= 'ERROR: Max. username length is ' . USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH;
```

I get this error with the code provided above:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'
```

The error occurs for the line in which the $test variable is defined.

I'm using `PHP 5.5.12` version.

Why?

Comment: You cannot concatenate values when declaring class properties. Use the constructor for that. Although with your example it doesn't really make sense to do it either way.

Comment: I wanted to make an constant for the message, but i can't include one constant in another. Or can i?

Comment: There is no reason at all imho to create a constant for stuff like this. If the requirements change you will have to go into the actual class to change this. If the language changes you basically for no option at all. If you need to add more tests your are also kinda stuck.

Comment: @PeeHaa so how would you do it then? Just put this text into the methods?

Comment: No the actual texts should be handled outside of this class by a dedicated translation object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56821/discussion-between-tastro-and-peehaa).

Comment: Wikipedia about translation object: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) given by PeeHaa in chat. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define variable `$test` inside the constructor like this:

```
class yourClass{
    private $test;
    function __construct(){
        const USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = '2';
        $this->test = 'Max. username length is ' . USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH;
    }
}
```

This only works in `PHP 5.6`:

`private $test = 'Max. username length is ' . USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH;`

Comment: @tastro Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: i did now and it works. Thank you! But it's an odd way to do this. :/ OMG at PHP. xD

Comment: I chose this answer as my accepted answer, because it provides a solution for my problem. But i think that people with this problem should read @Evert answer as well. It's good to know why it happens.

Answer (score 3):

Expressions in property declarations are not (yet) supported by PHP. Some expressions will be allowed from PHP 5.6 onwards. You can read more about it on [PHP's wiki](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs).

Your specific example *should* work in PHP 5.6.

Comment: Good to know. Is there a workaround for `PHP 5.5`? As i can't upgrade to `PHP 5.6` on my server for now. :( +1

Comment: I think you already accepted the workaround ;) But yea.. lacking support for these expressions implies you need to do this stuff in a constructor.

Comment: I know that i already accepted the workaround. But it's always good to know if there are others ways of doing things. I can always change my accepted answer if there should be a better solution. ;)